# Should the feminism tag exist on this site?

Tags: discussion, tags, burnination

The [feminism](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feminism) tag is apparently unwelcome on this forum. There are only 3 questions tagged with [feminism](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feminism) ([my own included](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/208469/105798)). One of the other 2 was [closed as opinion-based](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32076/is-there-a-generally-accepted-critical-and-or-feminist-response-to-heinleins-wo). That leaves a [single question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179796/did-heinlein-intend-to-portray-men-and-women-as-equals) related to feminism.

Should this tag even exist on this site?

Comment: `The feminism tag is apparently unwelcome on this forum` What has given you that determination about that tag? Just because people didn't like *your* questions, doesn't mean that now no one else can ask about the topic.

Comment: An 'unpopular' tag can still be useful and relevant.

Comment: I edited your title so that voting on the question is unambiguous whether it's about agreeing with the body ("should it exist") or the former title ("do we get rid of it"). Feel free to rollback. I hope this didn't invalidate anyone's votes (well, at least that would prove the ambiguity...)

Comment: @Jenayah - Based on the voting patterns and comments, I'm guessing that the downvotes reflect that people don't think the question should have been asked in the first place, rather than their dislike of the tag.

Comment: @Valorum: Indeed, voting on the *answers* is probably more instructive than voting on the *questions,* at least in this case. But probably in general, too; meta voting on questions is very slippery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a significant amount of consideration of the points raised by other answers to this question (@Jenayah in particular, thank you), as well as constructive feedback from the comments to [my question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/208469/are-there-any-examples-of-feminist-works-in-the-sword-and-sorcery-genre), I have successfully managed to salvage that question from a *-6* to a *+10*, and I'd like to summarize what I've found (from a sample size of 1, mind you) that this community appears to support.

I'm arguing in favor of keeping the `feminism` tag, but clarifying the tag usage to recommend that questions using it may benefit from considering the specific years of cited works in order to determine the context of feminism at the time the works were produced. I believe this was the critical piece that was missing from my question, which, after adding, gave a commonly understandable point of reference, so that the question and answer can be understood in its appropriate context. My question in particular was related almost entirely to *Second-Wave Feminism*, however, without that additional information and a common understanding of the term, the question could be easily interpreted differently when interpreted as *Fourth-Wave Feminism*.

I've done my best to extract some themes that could be easily identified in literature, movies and other published content, as they would be relevant to each iteration of the feminist movements, and, furthermore, mapped to a continuous timeline that covers most if not all of the Science Fiction & Fantasy works discussed in this community. Of course, there were no hard boundaries for the applicable dates, nor were there necessarily any unanimous agreements on these definitions. However, I believe these are appropriate and useful for application to the `feminism` tag on this site, as well as respectful to the movements. I would sincerely appreciate further discussion on this topic. I hope this helps, and if it doesn't, at least I tried.

**First-Wave Feminism** (~1871-1960)

- official legal inequalities

**Second-Wave Feminism** (~1961-1990)

- sexuality
- family
- the workplace (or appropriate trade, profession, or peer group)
- reproductive rights
- de facto inequalities (e.g., physical, biological)
- official legal inequalities

**Third-Wave Feminism** (~1991-2007)

- abolishing gender-role stereotypes
- expanding feminism to include women with diverse racial and cultural identities
- focus on individualism

**Fourth-Wave Feminism** (~2008-present)

- oriented around social media for organization and mobilization
- empowerment of women

  - justice against assault and harassment
  - equal pay for equal work
  - bodily autonomy
  - speak against abusers of power
  - provide opportunities for girls and women
- advocates for men in addition to women

  - greater opportunities to be engaged parents
  - free expression of emotions and feelings
  - free to present themselves as they wish

Comment: +1 definitely in favor of keeping it. Considerations of gender roles, sexuality, social organization and political issues are core to many works of scifi (I'd argue they are a *sine qua non* for most of Ursula K. LeGuin works, for example. They are also heavily present in James Tiptree Jr's works. And I'm mentioning just two authors I'm familiar with).

Answer (score 2):

## Not on account of the given reason(s)

### Unpopularity contest

You have determined that this tag is unpopular, however, an unpopular tag can still be useful. It may become more popular, or widely-used in time.

Besides, you said it yourself, there is already a post that uses the tag, and is actually using it correctly and successfully. Are you saying that post not longer deserves to have that tag?

### Jerk that knee

It seems to me that you've had an unpleasant experience using this tag on a post, and consequently knee-jerk reacting.

Let's not dummy-spit, let's work to improve what's here. There are some related questions that could potentially benefit from this tag, and in fact might even improve the site's searchability if we did add them, for example:

- [Do Lord of the Rings or The Silmarillion pass the Bechdel test?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/48945/21267)
- [Is there significance to the all-female main characters in Annihilation?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/184116/21267)
- [A (very sexualized) women controlled world, where the main character joins the resistance](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/166468/21267)

Not to mention that we have the [bechdel-test](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bechdel-test) and the [female-characters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/female-characters) tags that could work to compliment to each other.

Comment: Definitely don't put the tag on that last question, all these story ID  exclusive tags aren't very helpful.

Comment: _"there is already a post that uses the tag, and is actually using it correctly and successfully. Are you saying that post not longer deserves to have that tag?"_ first, there's no correct usage because there's literally no guidance on that one. Plus, I'm sure someone could wrap up an elaborate question about, say, [insert political ideology] in a SFF world, that still doesn't make it a "deserved" tag.

Answer (score -1):

We should get rid of it, although as the previous answer said, not on account of given reasons but per the burnination criteria listed on [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/398063) on main Meta:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

The contents, I guess... But unambiguous? Definitions of feminism vary almost with every person, so yes, it is ambiguous.

2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Not really, no. Admittedly this criterion is a bit more relevant on technical sites like SO (see original meta post), but no, feminism isn't, overall, especially SFF. We do have ambiguous but on-topic tags [elves](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elves), [tag: androids]...

3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

Kinda? Actually, probably more than [elves](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elves); on non-ID stuff at least. That criterion is probably a pass.

4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Back to #1: no, it doesn't. And this ambiguity does cause closure, because "feminism", unless very explicitly defined in the question, is often unclear and POB.

Furthermore, like Möoz pointed out, surely [female-characters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/female-characters) can take care of whatever [feminism](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feminism) would leave out. I think the former is also a crappy tag, but that's a discussion for another day.

Comment: I appreciate the constructive discussion on this topic. In the question that spawned this conversation, I've added some specific criteria directly from Second Wave Feminism. Would the same criteria (sexuality, family, the workplace, reproductive rights, de facto inequalities, official legal inequalities) be suitable for the tag definition?

Comment: "Furthermore, like Möoz pointed out, surely [tag:female-characters] can take care of whatever [tag:feminism] would leave out." -1, that's ridiculous. Female characters are an extremely narrow piece of feminism (and of course you can have female characters without being feminist at all).

Comment: @Kevin in real world, sure, but on SFF, I'd expect most feminism question to involve female characters and their treatment. Our FC tag sucks, though. It's not used in any kind of consistent way, and wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: Disagreed. Feminism and explorations of sexuality, gender roles and societal issues related to them are *a core aspect* of many works of scifi, and integral to the works of (to name just two examples) Ursula K. Le Guin and James Tiptree Jr. That it's not a completely defined and unambiguous term is not relevant in my opinion; "scifi" itself and its many tropes are not not entirely well defined either, and there are raging debates about whether particular works can be considered scifi, fantasy or neither. Finally, the tag itself is useful because *not all* scifi explores these issues.